# One line If statement with Razor and .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, if-statement

Razor doesn't seem to like my one line `If` statements... Normally in VB.NET, I can write a one line `If` statement like so:

```
If True Then Dim x As Integer
```

However, when I do the same with Razor in a `.vbhtml` file like this...

```
@If True Then Dim x As Integer
```

I get the error

> *The "If" block was not terminated. All "If" statements must be terminated with a matching "End If"*.

What gives? Why won't Razor take this? I realize that a simple solution is to just use a code block like

```
@code
    If True Then Dim x As Integer
End Code
```

But thats not what I'm looking for. I'm curious why Razor can't recognize a VB.Net one line `If` statement using just `@If...`. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating the Razor code in `()`?

Comment: @user1477388 No luck there either.

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot Enclose your Razor code in `@{....}`

Comment: @BhushanFirake Thanks but this isn't c#. That is also the equivalent of `@code` in my example, which is not what im looking for.

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot Yes , it is C# code but Razor view engine

Comment: Razor does not permit the 'shorthand' of one-line `if` statements.  You must delimit your blocks regardless of how many statements.

Comment: @BhushanFirake Yes, `@{` is equivalent to `@Code`. Please reread my question though - I am not looking for a block code solution. I am specifically wondering why `@If` does NOT work.

Comment: Why not just write something like `Dim x As Integer = (If(true, 1, 0))`

Comment: @TimBJames That would work but also needs to be in an `@Code` block as Razor wont let you start a line with `@Dim`. Looks like `@Code` might be required in this situation anyway.

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot Yeah you will still need `@Code` regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem with C#, As explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx) :

> Razor uses code syntax to infer indent: Razor Parser infers code
>   ending by reading the opening and the closing characters or HTML
>   elements. In consequence, the use of openings “{“ and closings “}” is
>   mandatory, even for single line instructions

You do the wright thing

```
@code
    If True Then Dim x As Integer
End Code
```

You can do it like that but it's not you like (inline)

```
@If (True) Then
    Dim x As Integer
End If
```

Answer (score 7):

In VB.Net you do a inline If Statement like this:

```
@(If(boolCondition, "truePart", "falsePart"))
```

Comment: This is the real solution

Comment: This is a ternary If expression, not an If statement. What if you want to conditionally call a helper or extension method which doesn't return a value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about VB, but this works in C#.

```
@{if (true) { int x; }}
```